# How to include a file in Django as a Background cover

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

So basically, I'm new to Django and I have been experimenting with Django in building my website portfolio. I decided to experiment with Django if I could use python, JS, Bootstrap, CSS and HTML at the same time, all went well till I came to an obstacle which has been a hassle to overcome. Initially, in my static folder, I have a folder called CSS that contains a file of CSS as main.css and another folder within the Static folder, called Images which contains some Jpg images.

So after writing my code in my base folder as home.html, I then proceeded to the main.css folder and wrote:

```
  *{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
    font-family: Heebo,sans-serif;
}

.Landing {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background:url("./images/Laptop.jpg");
    background-size: cover;

}
```

So basically where the initial problem is(Where I labeled #4), when I host my server I was expecting the image to come up in the background of the website, but it didn't. I then proceeded to think it should be a URL or calling problem, so instead of using a URL I tried:

```
<img  src="{% static 'images/Laptop.jpg' %}" >
```

But this at #4 didn't show up on the background of the page either, and I had doubts that it would show up because that's more of HTML than CSS.
At this moment I'm out of ideas and wanted to see if anyone has any solution which could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The image format is different both paces you have mentioned. One ends with .jpg and other .jpeg.

Comment: Based on what I can see here, the answer provided does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the full path for the image
Like /static/images/Laptop.jpg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).